# Prevent page refresh after pressing PrimeFaces' button

Tags: jsf, button, primefaces

I have a web page with a `p:tabView` and some `p:tab` inside. In one of these tabs (which is not the default one) there is a `p:commandLink` that, on click, updates and displays a `p:dialog` containing a `p:button`.

My problem is that after clicking the button in the dialog, the page refreshes and shows again the default tab. Instead, I want the button to close the dialog without refreshing the page. In other words, I want the button to trigger an action on the server side, and on the client side to behave like the `x` close link in the top right corner of the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve it with PrimeFaces v3.0.RC2's [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/requestContext.jsf):

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dialog">  
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{mrBean.close}" value="Close" />  
</p:dialog>

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MrBean {
   public void close() {
      RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
      context.execute("dialog.hide();"); 
      //On primefaces >= 3.x use context.execute("PF('dialog').hide();");
   }
}
```

Comment: This works, but it's not the most direct solution which is, I have got from your answer, to use p:commandButton instead of p:button. This lets you use actionListener="mrBean.doSomething" type="Button" oncomplete="dialog.hide()" which is enough without need to disturb RequestContext

Comment: :P haha sry.. I read too fast and mis-understood that you wanted to do it on the server side